# Python EOF shortcut on Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, eof

Hello i worte this simple program for encripting stings.
It requires from user to enter a simple string after doing that user shoud hit EOF shortcut (CTRL+D or CTRL+Z) but nothing than entering ^D or ^Z happens. Everything is fine when I do this on Ubuntu (using CTRL+D), but on windows this problem occurs. (Windows 10, python 2.7) Is there any other way to enter EOF in userinput in console.
Program:

```
import string
table = string.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm")
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.rstrip()
    print string.translate(line, table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.stdin.readline()` that provides automatic EOL
Once you hit `CTRL D` , the program will quit gracefully.

**Modified Code**

```
import string
import atexit
import sys
#import fileinput

table = string.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm")

while  True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline() #readline returns EOF by default after read
    if line:                    #If data is read
        line = line.rstrip()    #read line and remove whitespace
        print string.translate(line, table) #print translated string
    else:
        sys.exit(0)             #exit on 'CTRL D'
```

**Program Output**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
wefjdjbgngfpbgf
jrswqwotatscots
jgnfrejgrtnhkeritrevndsksdlv
wtaserwtegauxrevgeriaqfxfqyi
>>>
```